# C : mark the every struct, union, array elements

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I want to show how stack is allocated through pointers on struct, union, array
I just have no clue how to approach. The following is my try.

```
// to check the boundary
char *minimum_pointer, *maximum_pointer ;

// to check marked
void markmark(char *x, int size, char marking_address) {
  minimum_pointer = x;
  maximum_pointer = minimum_pointer + size;
  // is this correct?
  // I am trying to place marking_address 
  //   to every byte of x

  if (*minimum_pointer>marking_address || *maximum_pointer<marking_address) {
    printf("%s \n", "out of boundary");
  }

  int number_of_array_element = size/sizeof(char);
  for (int i=0; i<number_of_array_element; i++) {
    if (&x[i] >= minimum_pointer && &x[i] <= maximum_pointer) {
     x[i] = marking_address;
     // am I doing this right?
     // I need to place the address to every byte of input x
   }
  }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  struct structure_example {
    char* a ;
    char b[20] ;
    float c ;
  } str_ex;
  markmark((char *) &str_ex, sizeof(str_ex), 0xa1);

  union union_example {
    float a ;
    char b ;
    int c ;
  } uni_ex;
  markmark((char *) &uni_ex, sizeof(uni_ex), 0xa2);

  char arr_ex[50] ;
  markmark((char *) &arr_ex, sizeof(arr_ex), 0xa3);

  return 0;
}
```

My question is

```
  maximum_pointer = minimum_pointer + size;
  // is this correct?
  // I am trying to place marking_address 
  //   to every byte of x
```

And another question is

```
  int number_of_array_element = size/sizeof(char);
  for (int i=0; i<number_of_array_element; i++) {
    if (&x[i] >= minimum_pointer && &x[i] <= maximum_pointer) {
     x[i] = marking_address;
     // am I doing this right?
     // I need to place the address to every byte of input x
   }
  }
```

What is confusing me is that
how and what do I need to initialize the struct and union and array.

Thanks,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you want the address of the stack then `minimum_pointer = x` is not correct, that would only make `minimum_pointer` point to the same thing x points to i.e.

```
char* p = "42";
markmark(p, ...
```

it doesn't say anything about the stack, you need to take the address of x instead

```
minimum_pointer = &x;
```

i think if you look in the standard header file `stdarg.h` you can get some hints how to work with the stack.

Comment: I am confused. char *x means x is a pointer type? Do I need to reference again? Been so long away from C....

Comment: yes char* x means pointer, but you need the address of the pointer, not the pointer itself.